# Swapping sections of an array

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, data-structures

I was asked to make a function that swaps two sections in array.

Something like this,

```
array[] = {1 , 2, 5, 7, 8, a , b, c}
           |               |
sections:  First           Second
```

The signature is `void reverse_reg(int *arr, int s, int k, int j)` where `arr` is the array, `s` is the first index of the first section, `k` is the last index of the first section and `j` denotes the end of the second section, the start is `k` ( since indexing in **C** start from *0* )

So far I have something something like this,

```
void reverse_reg(int *arr, int s, int k, int j)
{
    for (int i = s; i < j; i++)
    {
        if (i > k / 2) /* swap the rest */
        {
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[j - i + 1]); /* this is wrong */
        }
        else
        {
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[k + i + 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tested the `else` block and so far it swaps successfully the second section, producing,

```
result:
a b c 7 8 1 2 5
```

Though, I haven't been able to find a way to swap the second part, since the `if` block, produces something completely wrong (and it makes sense), which makes me think that the initial logic is wrong. Any hints?

If it helps, the way I call the function is, `reverse_reg(arr, 0, 4, 8);`

The resulting array should be:

```
result:
a b c 1 2 5 7 8
```

Comment: Please clarify what the desired result is.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Yes I just added that. Sorry

Comment: 1) Reverse the whole array 2) Reverse each section. Or in the opposite order - whatever is more convenient.

Comment: hard question. ╔

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by @EugeneSh., a simple way is to reverse each section and then reverse the whole array. It could be as simple as:

```
void swap(int* i, int* j) {
    int k = *i;
    *i = *j;
    *j = k;
}

void reverse(int arr[], int len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len / 2; i++) {
        swap(arr + i, arr + len - i - 1);
    }
}

void reverse_reg(int* arr, int s, int k, int j) {
    // you use last index of initial section while I need index of second one
    ++k;
    reverse(arr + s, k - s);
    reverse(arr + k, j - k);
    reverse(arr + s, j - s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"12578abc"
"abc12578"
```

Assuming `array` is declared as `unsigned char array[8];`, this can be a rotate operation on 64-bit integer. Using a rotate function, we can shift `"abc"` to the left, and `"12578"` to the right, then combine their result:

```
uint64_t rot_left_64(uint64_t num, int n) 
{
    return (num << n) | (num >> (64 - n));
}

uint64_t num = 0x01020507080a0b0c;
num = rot_left_64(num , 8 * 5);
printf("%016llX\n", n); //output 0x0A0B0C0102050708
```